# Progressive Web App: The FetchEvent for "<URL>" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I am seeing the following errors in the console of my PWA:

1. The FetchEvent for "https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
2. The FetchEvent for "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.

It seems that external scripts have problems being fetched by workbox? The website is a next.js app and i am using next-pwa to turn it into a PWA. Here is the pwa-config for next-pwa: [next-pwa config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRLu7.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly common if you have a ad/tracking blocker extension installed, or if your browser has built-in blocking. A Workbox-powered service worker will not do anything to work around this blocking.

Comment: I don't believe this error is caused by any ad-block. I see when I go on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) (which is a PWA) with ad-block and check the console, I see a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error, but when I go to my site, [AniBrain](https://anibrain.ai/), I see a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`. Twitter's fail to load is based on ad-block, but mine doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The difference in logging may have to do with whether the blocking takes place in a request that is initiated inside the SW or not. Can you reproduce the issue in an Incognito Chrome window with no extensions active?

Comment: I **can** reproduce this in incognito mode of Brave Browser. Brave Browser has built in ad-block, but I have it disabled for the site. I **cannot** reproduce this in the other browsers (Safari, Edge, & Chrome) that have no ad block installed. So it seems this error is Brave Browser specific. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL is blocked by your CORS policy.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Please avoid the impression to ask a question instead of answering. You can e.g. phrase a conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is ... because ... ." Consider taking the [tour].